# How to verify a VCC generated Boogie program with Boogie?

Tags: c, verification

I'm trying to run VCC in order to verify C programs. I'm interested in the intermediate Boogie program that is produced by VCC (as I want to insert stuff there). To this end, VCC offers the option `/t`. However, when I try to run Boogie on the generated Boogie program, Boogie exists and complains about a lot of errors, which fall into three categories (the following are examples from my C code):

- `Error: undeclared identifier: $arch_ptr_size`
- `Error: undeclared type: $ctype`
- `Error: use of undeclared function: $in_range_i4`

The C program I want to verify is trivial (see below). VCC verifies it without a problem.

```
#include <vcc.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    _(assert i == 0)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there Boogie options I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call Boggie with the additional file `Vcc3Prelude.bpl`.